# Python Pandas Group by Count Pivot of multiple colunms

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

Given the Header as TimStamp, Gender, and Race,
I would like to have the count of Gender and Count of Race Group by the Time Stamp. Given Gender = M/F Race = A/B/C/D/E .

**Race = E may not exist in the dataSet, but anticipate data with Race E. 
Hence a Place Holder is Important with value Zero.**

Example of Data and output shows below.

> Time_stamp
>   12:30,
>   12:30,
>   12:30,
>   12:30,
>   12:31,
>   12:31,
>   12:32,
>
> Gender = 
>   M,
>   F,
>   F,
>   F,
>   M,
>   F,
>   M
>
> Race = 
>   A,
>   A,
>   B,
>   B,
>   C,
>   A,
>   D
>
> [image: enter code here]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do two pivot tables for that:

For achieving a table with all the specified categories in `Race`you need to convert `Race` to categorical variable:

```
df["Race"] = pd.Categorical(df.Race, categories=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
```

For gender:

```
 df_g =  df.groupby(["Time_stamp", "Gender"], observed=False).count().fillna(0).unstack()
```

And for Race:

```
df_r = (df.groupby(["Time_stamp", "Race"], observed=False)
        .count().fillna(0).reset_index()
        .astype({"Race": str}).pivot_table(index="Time_stamp", columns="Race"))
```

And then you can join them:

```
df_report = df_r.join(df_g)  
df_report.columns = df_report.columns.droplevel()
```

Comment: I liked your answer, well as we see the discription, we need to have a Col E, which was not given in DataSet we got.My apologies for not highligting that point. Any ways, thanks a lot for answering, hope your answer may be polished as per the bold Note . Race = E may not exist in the dataSet, but anticipate data with Race E. 
Hence a Place Holder is Important with value Zero. So we need to have Race = A/B/C/D/E Placed forefront.

Comment: Cool! no problem :D. I fixed it. Now you should see all the columns. If I managed to help you, please, consider selecting my answer as accepted answer :D